# Xamarin Forms with Touch ID Fingerprint Authentication

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am developing a multi-platform app with Xamarin Forms. I need to support Touch ID/fingerprint authentication for both the iOS and Android platforms. How can I do this? I am new to Xamarin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use a [Dependency Service](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/dependency-service/) for platform-specific behavior. Look to the linked guide as a starting point.

Answer (score 19):

I've developed a Plugin for this. It's available on NuGet, too. Feel free, to drop an issue, if you miss something, or found an error.

https://github.com/smstuebe/xamarin-fingerprint

**In general**: There are alot of Plugins that abstract platform specific behavior. Before you write something on your own, just google for *"<feature> xamarin plugin"*. It will safe much time.

Comment: Better than googling just open the NuGet manager and search on it, faster than googling.

Comment: Very useful advice to Xamarin beginners

Comment: sometimes you need to right the code yourself rather then using a nugget like i went to one of the bank where they disable the nuget installation and ask me to code the functionality which was already been provided by nuget  Reason : there could be some miscellaneous in it which may leak ur data

Comment: @RonakShethia most plugins (all that I know) are open source. So you can check  the code and use the nuget or you just copy the code.